# Issue with SSR and React dynamic component imports

Tags: reactjs, express, server-side-rendering, tsconfig

I am creating a Server-Side Rendered app using React. I am sending the same component from the backend, as I am, the frontend. Everything in my repository is working great, except I can't dynamically import other components into my App.tsx when trying to view this from the server "start" script. My "dev" script with webpack works great, so what the heck is going on here? Link to my repo: https://github.com/Brent-W-Anderson/boilerplate

-Thank you for the help

Comment: I had actually found the fix myself to this issue. It looks like I was missing a few things. The biggest changes I made were to splitting the webpack and tsconfig files to be server/client specific and then adding in a separate index.html for the client and views/index.hbs for the server, so it could populate the handlebars with the react <App />. Here's a link to the new repo: https://github.com/Brent-W-Anderson/boilerplate/tree/SSR-TEMPLATE